# Express interpolating polynomial as a linear combination of interpolating polynomials for subintervals

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Given a set of points $(x_i, u_i), \; i = 1, \dots, n$ (for my application $n = 5$) one can construct an interpolating polynomial
$$
P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \ell_i(x), \quad \operatorname{deg} P = n - 1.
$$
Let's consider the big stencil $S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ and the small (partial) stencil $S_i = \{x_i, x_{i+1}, \dots, x_{i+p}\}$ of $p+1$ consecutive points. On each of those partial stencils one can also build an interpolating polynomial of degree $p$. Let's denote them by
$
P_i(x), \; \operatorname{deg} P_i = p.
$

It seems that $P(x)$ is expressible in terms of $P_i(x)$ and weighting functions $\gamma(x)$, depending only on $x_i$:
$$
P(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - p} \gamma_i(x) P_i(x).
$$

For example, given the set of points $\left\{(-2, u_{-2}), (-1, u_{-1}), (0, u_0), (1, u_1), (2, u_2)\right\}$ 
$$
P_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} u_{-2} x (x+1)-u_{-1} x
   (x+2)+\frac{1}{2} u_0 (x+1)
   (x+2)\\
P_2(x) = u_0 \left(1-x^2\right)+\frac{1}{2}
   u_{-1} (x-1) x+\frac{1}{2} u_1 x
   (x+1)\\
P_3(x) = \frac{1}{2} u_0 (x-1)(x-2)-u_1 (x-2)
   x+\frac{1}{2} u_2 (x-1) x
$$
corresponding weights are
$$
\gamma_1(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x-1)}{12}\\
\gamma_2(x) = \frac{4-x^2}{6}\\
\gamma_3(x) = \frac{(x+2)(x+1)}{12}.
$$
From now I've found the weights by solving a linear system, but I'm looking for a more intelligent way of finding the weighting polynomials.

Comment: cf https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_schema

Comment: @user251257 Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for